# How to install Firefox and Firefox Aurora in parallel?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, software-installation

I would like to install Firefox Aurora in parallel with the "release" version of Firefox.
I do not want to replace the release version.

I managed to do this with Firefox nightly but not with Aurora.

OS : Precise
Browser : Firefox 16

Comment: How did you do this with the nightly build (which you report did work)? Please provide details about that, and also explain what method or methods you've tried for installing Aurora. This should make it possible to identify specifically the differences that are causing one way to succeed and the other to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest aurora build from here

[mozilla download](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-aurora/)

extract it and move it to **/opt/firefox/aurora** or what ever you wanna call the folder.

and simply run **/opt/firefox/aurora/firefox**

Comment: for install the nightly build version I have used this command :sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk                                                      and in the aim ton install firefox-aurora I have add this PPA sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora

Comment: I just try the stefan way and it works very well, I just add a new entry in the launcher with alacarte. Thank you both.